# Semantically 'correct' method of styling a label using the CSS :checked property

Tags: html, css, forms, accessibility, semantic-markup

Working on a form that has some custom radio button styling and wanted to check the way I normally do this.

To avoid Javascript, I typically have a radio input wrapped inside a label and a div following the input. I then style the div depending on the checked state.

This is some example markup:

```css
label input:checked ~ span {
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<label for="10000">
        <input type="radio" id="10000" name="coveramount" value="10000">
        <span>&pound;10,000</span>
    </label>
```

(there's normally classes on the elements)

Is the span inside a label correct? Is there a better way of doing this with another tag or similar for accessibility?

Comment: Check it with couple of screen readers, it should be no problem. However, you could also use pseudo-element.

Comment: I've seen lots of similar solutions in production code. It's not ideal, but this will persist until we get actual radio buttons that can be styled with css.

Comment: If you do implicit labels `<label>Words<input></label>`, you do not need to use @for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTML in your question is fine.  This is a very simple and reliable way of styling radio and checkbox elements.

There are some potential accessibility issues to watch out for, more to do with the CSS than the HTML.

Will the `<input>` element itself be visible, in your design?  It's common to hide the actual radio/checkbox input, and use CSS background images to provide fancy-looking versions of the checked and unchecked states.  If you do this, remember to:

- Provide focus styles for sighted keyboard users, using something like `label input:focus ~ span`
- Avoid using `display:none`, `visibility:hidden`, or the HTML `hidden` attribute to hide the real radio/checkbox.  These will all prevent the input from being operable by keyboard-only users, and screen reader users (pointer users can click on the `<label>` element).  That's because they all cause the input to be removed from the keyboard tabbing order, and removed from the accessibility tree which is sent to assistive tech.  If you need to hide the real input element, use an approach like Bootstrap's `.sr-only` class or HTML5Boilerplate's `.visuallyhidden` class. For more detail about this, see:

  - this [real-world bug report for the Eleven  Drupal admin theme](https://github.com/thememachine/eleven/issues/161)
  - [Short note on the accessibility of styled form controls](https://developer.paciellogroup.com/blog/2018/07/short-note-on-the-accessibility-of-styled-form-controls/), which includes code demonstrations of styling radios.

Another potential issue is with use of colour.  Don't rely on a change of colour alone to indicate a checked control, that's a WCAG failure.  Native radios and checkboxes involve a shape change (i.e. the bullet which fills the circle).  Be aware that CSS colours get overridden when a Windows High Contrast theme is in use.  If `background: red` is the *only* clue to a checked (or focused) radio option, Windows High-Contrast users won't know what's going on.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I normally position the input absolutely with a negative left value. The focus state is a good point for me to check.

Comment: I work at a high traffic form conversion based company and we're not sure on how many users are using screen readers or anything else, Google Analytics doesn't seem to offer anything there.

Comment: Hiding the input by putting it way outside the viewport is fine too.  The important thing is it remains in the focus tabbing order.

Comment: The reason these analytics tools don't report screen readers, is that they have no way of knowing.  The user-agent is the browser; the screen reader is an adaptive layer on top the host operating system accessibility APIs.  The browser and screen reader are effectively communicating thorough a middle man (though there are some weird exceptions, like JAWS which hooks directly into some browser processes).

Comment: If it's just screen reader traffic numbers you want, you're out of luck.  But if you want better insight to how screen readers are used, the [WebAIM screen reader user surveys](https://webaim.org/blog/survey7results/) and HeydonWorks [screen reader strategy survey](http://www.heydonworks.com/article/responses-to-the-screen-reader-strategy-survey) are good starting points.

Comment: Awesome thanks for the replies again! Our company doesn't get any organic traffic but I was curious if there were any users on screen readers.

Answer (score 0):

**Refer :** [After Pseudo Element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after)

Use `::after` or `::before` `pseudo-elements`, and adjust content accordingly.

```css
label input:after {
  content: '10,000';
  font-size: 20px;
  height: 1em;
  position: relative;
  left: 20px;
}
label input:checked::after {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<label for="10000">
    <input type="radio" id="10000" name="coveramount" value="10000">
</label>
```

**Update :**

- **Not a good and proper solution** as using a pseudo element on an input element won't render anything in Firefox or Edge

Comment: Thanks, I've tried pseudo elements before with this but it feels wrong without any actual text within the label, and the content attribute doesn't pad out the element. There's plenty of designs where I cannot give a fixed width and height.

Comment: @Lovelock Yes, you're right, i also follow the `label` approach as it gives some much freedom to adjust the values inside label. As in this case pound symbol was difficult to get with pseudo element. Thats why, i have just shown demo without pound symbol which is easily visible via label approach.

Comment: `content: '\A3 10,000';` will give you a pound sign, but note that using a pseudo element on an input element won't render anything in Firefox or Edge.

Comment: @Alohci Yup, i tested this thing on chrome.

Comment: Last time I checked, Internet Explorer doesn't announce pseudo-elements in screen readers.

Comment: This is totally over-engineered.  The question was about radio buttons, so presumably there's more than one input/label.  So you'd need to provide CSS generated content for each radio input.  It would end up needing something more like `label input#10000:after { content: '10,000'; }`, `label input#20000:after { content: '20,000'; }`, and another CSS rule for EVERY radio button!  It's also tricky to maintain, because changing a form option means updating the HTML input and the corresponding CSS rule too.  The questioner's original approach is much more practical.